# Looking for FTP Server Java library

Tags: java, ftp, database

I'm looking for Java FTP Server library, which lets to replace DAL with lets say a DB data. 
So far, i saw that in **Apache FtpServer** there is an option to intercept some of the commands using *FTPLet* container, however it is missing the most important command such as LIST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apache FtpServer you can intercept any command with an Ftplet, including LIST. Implement the Ftplet interface and override the beforeCommand or afterCommand (depending on if you want to handle the request or the response). Those methods will be called for every command sent to the server.

But, from your question, you might instead be interested in instead implementing a custom file system. Look at the FileSystemFactory, FileSystemView and FtpFile interfaces.